# Не проходит авторизацию пользователь AD пока он в сети Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, авторизация

Всем доброго времени суток. Поднял Ubuntu 20.04, ввёл в домен.
Однако обнаружилось, что пользователь, после перезагрузки не может войти в систему под доменной учёткой.
НО, если отрубить от сети, то он может зайти в систему.

Подскажите куда копнуть нужно, пжлст.

auth.log

```
Nov  2 13:21:43 n-03 sshd[123991]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.121.11  user=iadmin@mydomain.local
Nov  2 13:21:43 n-03 sshd[123991]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.121.11 user=iadmin@mydomain.local
Nov  2 13:21:45 n-03 sshd[123991]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user iadmin@mydomain.local: 4 (System error)
Nov  2 13:21:45 n-03 sshd[123991]: Failed password for iadmin@mydomain.local from 10.16.23.11 port 49946 ssh2
Nov  2 13:21:45 n-03 sshd[123991]: fatal: Access denied for user iadmin@mydomain.local by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Comment: как обычно: начните с логов того, что настраивали в этой системе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причиной недоступности было нестандартное размещение ПК в домене. Если перегнать в стандартное, то всё работает. При вводе ПК в домен. Он падает в дэфолтное размещение - Computers. При перемещении в другие, руками созданные, папки (OU если не ошибаюсь), в моём случае, Ubunta не смогла получить данные с АД.